# .contains() does not accept as arguments an element of array when looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, contains

I am looping through HTML elements and checking if they contain elements of my month array in italian. 
Problem is when I try to access the element of the array with month[i] returns nothing, when I write for example month[2], it returns true. I suppose that notation month[i] is not acceptable for contains. Has somebody solution. My code is under. Thanks.

```
const months = ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"];


for(i = 0; i < tdCellBody.length; i++){
        if(tdCellBody[i].classList.contains(months[i])) {
            console.log(true);
        } else {
            console.log(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question completely but the reason you are not able to compare it successfully might be you are checking 1 item with another not with the entire array.

Comment: `contains` should work with a [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). the dupe target isn't the right answer.

Comment: @Archer wrong dupe. She uses `contains` already.

Comment: as it looks like, you need another loop for the month array and check against. if you add a purpose of the checking, it could be written shorter, depending on further actions.

Comment: @Nina it works  when I pass an variable as argument, there is not problem for this, but when I pass as argument element of an array, [i] - iterator is not recognized, or there is another notation that I must use, which I don't know.

Comment: the syntax is right, but the index `i` is from `tdCellBody`, not from `month`. please add some html code for getting a runnable (or not ...) script.

Comment: @NIna, unfortunately I don't have HTML code, because, all the data is being generated from the JS script. This is only a small code snippet from a complex Calendar project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses only one node to check against an array of given values.

```js
var months = ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"],
    node = document.getElementById('div1'),
    j;

for (j = 0; j < months.length; j++) {
    console.log(months[j], node.classList.contains(months[j]));
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="Marzo Maggio"></div>
```